# Why I'm not required to specify a type argument when using a Generic class?

Tags: java

I was surprised today when this code compiled:

```
class GenericClass<T> {
    public void emptyMethod(T instance) {
        // ..
    }

    public void print(T instance) {
        System.out.println(instance);
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericClass first = new GenericClass();
        System.out.println("Wow");
        first.emptyMethod(10);
        first.print(16);
    }

}
```

The compiler emits a warning (Type safety: The method emptyMethod(Object) belongs to the raw type GenericList. References to generic type GenericList should be parameterized), but anyway it does not cause a compiler error and it runs 'fine' (at least the provided print method). As I'm understanding, the compiler is using object as the type argument, but I find it counter-intuitive. Why would the compiler do such thing? Why it doesn't require me to specify the type parameter?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using a *raw* class, basically.

Think back to when generics were first introduced in Java: there was a load of code which already used `List`, `ArrayList` etc. In order to avoid breaking all of that code, but still reusing the existing classes, raw types were introduced - it's basically using a generic type as if it weren't one.

As you can see, you get a warning - so it's worth avoiding - but that's the primary reason for it being allowed at all.

See [section 4.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8) of the JLS for more information, which includes:

> Raw types are closely related to wildcards. Both are based on existential types. Raw types can be thought of as wildcards whose type rules are deliberately unsound, to accommodate interaction with legacy code. Historically, raw types preceded wildcards; they were first introduced in GJ, and described in the paper Making the future safe for the past: Adding Genericity to the Java Programming Language by Gilad Bracha, Martin Odersky, David Stoutamire, and Philip Wadler, in Proceedings of the ACM Conference on Object-Oriented Programming, Systems, Languages and Applications (OOPSLA 98), October 1998.

Comment: Was just going to write that backwards compatability was the answer, but you beat me to it :) +1.

Comment: Oh, you're really, really fast. Thank you very much. I think I was searching with the wrong words :S . Now it makes sense.

Comment: When it comes to Java, backwards compatibility strikes again.  And again.  And again...

Answer (score 2):

You have to know how generics are implemented in Java. They are far from perfect.
You have to remember that during run time everything is an Object. There are no types during run time.

Generics were added for added security in places, where you need it, but if you don't want to use it, you can ignore warnings and use unparametrized instances.

However, if you'd like java compiler to help you with type safety, then you parametrize generic class instances. Once you create a GenericClass for example, compiler will not allow you to use it with an integer parameter (first.emptyMethod(10) will not compile). You can still make it work with integer parameter if you do explicit type casting though.

So consider it a good practice for added security, which only works if you follow the rules.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have worked with Generics, but I was curious because that code (without type argument) compiled